# Why does this integral not converge?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a rather simple integral that I want to solve in Mathematica.

`Integrate[Sin[x*a/2]^4/x^1, {x, 0, Infinity}]`

where `a` is a real parameter larger than zero.

Upon putting this in Mathematica, it says the integral doesn't converge. Are there any tricks that I can use to make this converge, or can I trust Mathematica that it doesn't converge?

Comment: It is of the form 1/x, so what makes you think it does converge?

Comment: Well cause sin(x)/x is one for x to zero

Comment: But on the other end (x infinity) it doesn't… You can do 1 till infinity and it still does not converge. Looking at the far end is enough in this case…

Comment: It would converge if the exponent of `x` in denominator is bigger than `1`.

Comment: This is an analysis question as much as a Mathematica question. Yes, it diverges. One can bound it from below by a divergent sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first do the integral symbolically:

```
Integrate[Sin[x*1/2]^4/x^1, x]
```

which gives you:

```
1/8 (-4 CosIntegral[x] + CosIntegral[2 x] + 3 Log[x/2])
```

As you can see by filling in the bounds, the Log prevents it from being a finite value…

Answer (score 3):

If the sine function were not taken to an even power, its alternation of sign *would* give a convergent (though not absolutely convergent) integral. But, with that even power, the parts of the integral where $(\sin x)^4$ is $\ge 1/2$ gives a lower bound of the whole by a definitely divergent integral.

On another hand, if/when one really needs to make sense of "divergent integrals", especially in inner steps of a proof/computation, sometimes it does suffice to view the thing as a Fourier transform of a tempered distribution...  which not only "makes some sense", but is *compatible* with more classical styles of computation of integrals and such.